# Working with createReadStream in node.js using async/await

Tags: node.js, csv, asynchronous, async-await

After tried TFischer's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307139/how-to-asynchronously-createreadstream-in-node-js-with-async-await), I am still having difficulty with using `fs.creadReadStream` to process my csv file asynchronously:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const promises = [];
    fs.createReadStream(inputFile)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on("data", row => promises.push(processData(row, myRepository)))
        .on("error", reject)
        .on("end", async () => {
            await Promise.all(promises);
            resolve();
        });
});

async function processData(row, myRepository) {
    console.log('Current row: ', row);                          // logs all CSV rows
    
    const record = await myRepository.findOne({where: {id: row.id}});
    
    console.log(record);                                        // row.id is undefined here
    
    return record;
}
```

I want to be able to use `row` argument inside `processData(row, myRepository)` function as the current row of the actual CSV file being parsed but it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone explain what is happening there?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read chunks, `createReadStream` is your guy as it is already an async iterable:

```
async function main() {
  const reader = createReadStream(join(__dirname, "index.html"), "utf8");
  for await (const chunk of reader) {
    console.log(chunk);
  }
}
```